# Regressions with different time periods

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, stata

I'm trying to run a pooled OLS and fixed effects regression model using panel data but my problem is that my independent variables are measured monthly while my dependent variable is measured annually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies.  I'm running a pooled ols and fixed effects regression on explanatory variables for divorce. my explanatory variables are recorded monthly while divorce rates is recorded annually. I'm not sure what I can do other than look for annual explanatory variables which greatly reduces the amount of observations I have

Comment: What are the explanatory variables ?

Comment: Have you thought about an annual outcome with 12 monthly covariates for each explanatory variable?

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the post, and not only in comments. We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are often seen by few people!